# Kendo Toolbar event after render

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo UI [Toolbar](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/toolbar#events):

```
$("#toolbar").kendoToolBar({
        items : [ {
            type : "button",
            text : "List"
        } ]
})
```

and I have a script in my app that will translate strings according to the chosen language; i.e. it will find the word 'List' and change it to 'Liste'.

The problem is with timing.  There is a finite time that the Toolbar takes to render, so calling my translation function inside

```
$(document).ready(function() {    })
```

Is too early.

The Kendo Toolbar component doesn't have an `onRendered` event handler.  Otherwise I could use that.

Is there any way to define an event that occurs *after* all Kendo components, including Toolbar have been rendered?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Ain't there a better way to localize your page?

Besides that: I've created a small JavaScript function which waits until a given list of elements exist. Just call it as shown in the comment in `$(document).ready(function() { })`.

```
// E.g. waitUntilKendoWidgetsLoaded({ "toolbar": "kendoToolBar" }, doTranslation);
function waitUntilKendoWidgetsLoaded(widgets, action) {
    var allLoaded = true;
    for (var key in widgets) {
        if (widgets.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            allLoaded = allLoaded && $("#" + key).data(widgets[key]) !== undefined;
        }
    }

    if (allLoaded) {
        action();
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(waitUntilKendoWidgetsLoaded, 500, widgets, action);
    }
}
```

But be aware: The only thing you know for sure is that the element exists. It does not ensure that the element has finished loading. Especially with Kendo widgets which use a datasource you should use the existing events to trigger your function at the right moment.

Comment: polling is an interesting approach.. I think this needs a watchdog to avoid accidental infinite loops, etc . Pity if there's no event-driven way to achieve it.  If there is a better way to localize components rendered by 3rd party JS widgets I'm all ears